# Remove last N elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

hello so I have an array

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

const dynamic = 3
//remove from the last of the array dynamically
//I know I can pop an element from an array in javascript 
//removes from the last 
const pop = arr.pop(3) 
console.log(arr)
```

but what I really want to do is pop from the last array dynamically and get a result of
something like this with dynamic number ['a', 'b', 'c'] since javascript start count from Zero any help

Comment: see: [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: thanks a bunch

Comment: Specifically, `arr.splice(-3)` will remove last three elements and return them.